# Make field optional if condition is satisfied using .if(myCondition).optional() possible in express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using express-validator package and I would like to combine if and optional, something like this

I set config.requireFieldAB = false

```
await body("fieldAB")
   .if(config.requireFieldAB === false).optional()
   .isString()
   .bail()
   .withMessage(CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE)
   .run(req);
```

Running validation with above code always gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'run' in false
at ContextHandlerImpl.if (\node_modules\express-validator\src\chain\context-handler-impl.js:16:19)
at signupValidationRules (\controllers\myController.js:62:15)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The only way I can get it to work is if I do this

```
  if(config.requireFieldAB) {
    await body("fieldAB")
      .isString()
      .bail()
      .withMessage(RESPONSES.VALIDATION_ERROR)
      .run(req);
  }
```

That makes it optional, but I prefer to do it using first approach by .if().optional()

Is it even possible? If yes what am I doing wrong to cause "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'run' in false" error?

Comment: Try this `.if(v => config.requireFieldAB === false).optional()` The `.if` takes a function as a first param but you are passing in value of `config.requireFieldAB === false`

Answer (score 0):

as @molda said, you are passing a boolean expression to `.if` not a `function`.

you should do this:

```
body("fieldAB")
    .if(() => config.requireFieldAB === false)
    .optional()
    .isString()
    .bail()
    .withMessage(CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE),
```

or you could validate a field based on another request field value, ex:

```
    body("fieldAB")
        .if(async (value, { req }) => {
            // since we're in an async function we can fetch values from the database
            if(req.body.xField === 'some value') {
              // will validate
              return Promise.resolve()
            }
            // will not validate
            return Promise.reject()
         })
    .optional()
    .isString()
    .bail()
    .withMessage(CUSTOM_ERROR_MESSAGE),
```